# How to authenticate different websites users from multiple "users" tables, according to Laravel Passport client id (or user_id)

Tags: laravel, authentication, nuxt.js, laravel-passport

I'm using three different databases with my **Laravel** backend, basically, one is for the backend itself, a second one is for a `foo.com` **Nuxt** website and the third one is a `bar.com` **Angular** website. Each of these three databases have a `users` table looking like this:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Currently, each website is using **Laravel Passport** for authentification on the backend database. But now, I need the two websites `foo.com` and `bar.com` to use their own database `users` table for the authentification.

My **Laravel Passport** `oauth_clients` configuration looks like this:

```
+----+---------+------+---------------------------+----------+-----+
| id | user_id | name | secret | redirect         | provider | ... |
+----+---------+------+---------------------------+----------+-----+
|  1 |    null |  Foo | ****** | foo.com/callback |      foo | ... |
|  2 |    null |  Bar | ****** | bar.com/callback |      bar | ... |
+----+---------+------+---------------------------+----------+-----+
```

So, currently, users coming from `foo.com` sign in with their login/password through `foo` client and users coming from `bar.com` sign in with their login/password through `bar` client, but both on the backend `users` table.

How to force **Laravel** to use `foo.users` table for `foo.com` users and `bar.users` table for `bar.com` users ? Also, how to restrict `foo` users to use a `foo` middleware and `bar` users to use a `bar` middleware ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this by detecting the request hostname with $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].

Then you have to set up 3 different .env files for 3 different domains (.env, .foo.env and .bar.env), each with different database connection configurations.

At your bootstrap/app.php , you can add the code below:

```
$env  = '.env';
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'foo.com') {
    $env  = '.foo.env';
}
else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'bar.com') {
    $env  = '.bar.env';
}
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom($env);
```

I believe this is not the best option or best way to do it. But I believe you can achieve what you want with it.